# typescript event child to parent

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am still fairly new to this and angular 2 as well. I feel what I am about to ask you is pretty fundamental, however I just cannot wrap my head around it. So i have a component that we call container it contains child components that you can navigate too something like:

```
@Component({
   template:'<html> <router-outlet></router-outlet> </html>'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{

   @ViewChild(childComponent) childComponent:ChildComponent;
   constructor(){}

   ngOnInit(){
      if(childComponent){
         childComponent.myEvent.subscribe(row=>this.test(row));
      }
   }


    test(row:any){
       alert("I Fired");
    }
}

@Component({
template:'<some html></some html>'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
   myEvent = new EventEmitter();
   constructor(){}

  ngOnInit():void{
      this.myEvent.emit("some info");
  }
}
```

So the issue that i am having is that in the parent when it tries to subscribe to the event the `childComponent` is null. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way to subscribe to child events is through the template:

```
@Component({
   template:'<html> <router-outlet (myEvent)="test($event)"></router-outlet> </html>'  <-- Add the (myEvent) event handling here
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{

    @ViewChild(childComponent) childComponent:ChildComponent;
    constructor(){}  

    test(row:any){
        alert("I Fired");
    }
}

@Component({
    template:'<some html></some html>'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
    @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter();  <-- Use @Output() here
    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit():void{
        this.myEvent.emit("some info");
    }
}
```

You specify event the handler method in the parent component and pass $event as the parameter to the handler to pass what was emitted.